# Changing the shape of the overview marker in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, markers, map-overviews

I was wondering if it is possible to change the marker in an overview while working on an atlas in print composer of QGIS.
Could I change the shape of the marker to the actual form of the polygons in my coverage layer?

It would be neat to see the geometry in my overview map marked in whatever color I choose, instead of the little square frame that usually appears.

For example I would like the overview marker to be hexagonal as the geometry it is referring to, instead of square:[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved using a combination of Rule-based symbology and [Map Themes](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#configuring-map-themes).

1. Duplicate your grid layer (as it looks like you already have done). One will be used for your main map, the other for your overview map.
2. Set up your main grid symbology and create a map theme (mine is called 'grid'):

[image]

3. Set up your overview symbology using rule-based symbology with two rules:

   1. `$id = @atlas_featureid`
   2. `no filter`  (a blank expression)
4. Create another theme for your overview layer ('overview'):

[image]

5. In your layout, set your main map to the 'grid' theme and your Overview map to the 'overview' theme

[image]

**Result**:

As you change Atlas page, the symbology of your Overview map will change accordingly

[image]

**Note:**

You may have to enable symbol layers on your overview layer symbology to make sure the filtered 'overview' polygon appears on top of the unfiltered symbol layer:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, like it!

Comment: Nice! Thats works perfectly, thank you so much :)

Comment: @Jackie
 As a new user, please be adviced that this side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235